# Cómo Llamar un componente desde otro componente VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un componente Layout para mis páginas (views), allí tengo que llamar otro componente que tengo específico para hacer un reset de las contraseñas de mis usuarios.

Cuando llamo mi componente desde una vista funciona perfecto:
(La flecha roja es el botón que se crea desde el componente)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo llamo normal:

```js
import ResetPassword from "@/components/ValidateResetPassword";
export default {
  components: {
    TableBrowsers,ResetPassword
  },
}
```

```html
<ResetPassword v-bind:infoUser="infoReset"></ResetPassword>
```

y funciona perfectamente.

Ahora quiero llamar este mismo componente desde ese layout que hice, y lo estoy intentado hacer de la misma forma pero desde mi layout, el layout lo tengo ubicado así:

> appvue > src > components > layout > DefaultLayout.vue

Y el componente que quiero está en la ruta:

> appvue > src > components > ValidateResetPassword.vue

Y lo estoy intentado llamar igual, pero me sale el siguiente rol:

```js
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ResetPassword> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <DefaultLayout> at src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue
```

Como ya dije, lo llamo tal cual como en el view:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import ResetPassword from "@/components/ValidateResetPassword";
export default {
  components: {
    ResetPassword
  },
}
```

Lo llamo en un modal que tengo en el componente y lo llamo tal cual:

```html
<ResetPassword v-bind:infoUser="infoReset"></ResetPassword>
```

Pero no aparece, donde debería aparecer está en blanco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El componente no tiene nada raro, el script que tiene es este:

```js
export default {
  name: "resetpassword",
  data() {return{...}},
  props: {
    infoUser: {
      type: Object,
      default: []
    }
  },
  methods: {...},
}
```

Le coloqué ese `name` para ver si se solucionaba pero con o sin ese atributo falla.

**Nota**: Los `...` que hay en `data` y en `methods` solo indican que ahí hay contenido pero no es nada relevante para el problema.

Comment: Dice que no lo registraste, podrias mostrar DefaultLayout.vue?

Comment: Lo llamo tal cual como en el ejemplo de la vista, solo que este está dentro de components

Comment: Apaga y prende el servidor, o importa el componente sin el prefix @

Comment: Estoy en ambiente local, ya lo intenté con `../ValidateResetPassword` y no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es dado por las llamadas **Dependencias Circulares** en Vue, [Link Info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components).

Lo solucioné eliminando el llamado con `import` y en `components(){}` y agregue la siguiente línea:

```js
beforeCreate(){
    this.$options.components.ResetPassword = require('../ValidateResetPassword.vue').default
  }
```